# Is it possible to hide or encrypt the display name after login into the WordPress admin panel?

Tags: wordpress

Today, one of my clients asked the below question:

> I have login into the WordPress admin panel using the email id and
> password shared by you. Now what I did, after login right clicks on the
> page and click on inspect element then I search for my email id and I
> found my email id (shared screenshot below). I don't want to show my
> email like this. Either encrypt my email id or remove it from the
> inspect element. This is a security issue.

[image]

I explained to him that this will only show to the login user not everyone on the website and then the argument started.

I believe that this is the WordPress default functionality. I want to know if is there any way to handle this issue.

Comment: Anyone with access to the admin dashboard can see his email address. That's not something you can change. Your client can either a) make sure that only people he trusts get access to the admin dashboard, that way his contact details won't be exposed to strangers, b) use a different email address that he doesn't mind to share, c) remove his account from the site and have someone else manage it, or d) delete all of the other accounts from the website except his, that way no one can see his personal details, email included.

Comment: Display name can be set in profile settings from *Display name publicly as* dropdown select how you want to be showed.

Comment: @MartinMirchevcan Yes there is a dropdown and it's showing only 1 option value which is email id